# Undefined ia not an object(evaluating RCTCameraRollManager.getPhotos)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

I am using CameraRoll component to get photos.But i am getting undefined from CameraRoll.js file

```
var RCTCameraRollManager = require('NativeModules').CameraRollManager;
```

Here RCTCameraRollManager gets 'undefined'
In my scenario i am using CameraRoll component both for android and IOS.So how to update the node_modules file through command prompt

Comment: CameraRoll API has not yet been implemented for Android. I'm wondering what example you pulled your require string from above. I didn't see it in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html#content). Are you requiring react-native first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the later versions of React Native the Camera Roll manager is not required by default. To add it back, open Xcode. On the left side, drag the xcode file called `RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj` into the Libraries folder. Then expand it and drag from the Product folder the file called `libRCTCameraRoll.a` to the "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary with libraries". More info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html#content).

Comment: I can not find the library named libRCTCameraRoll.a in the folder

Comment: While adding RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj in your libraries folder expand the RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj folder in that you are having products folder expand product folder then you can able to find libRCTCameraRoll.a file